# Pre-Defined Operator Precedence

Tags: c, algorithm

I was gave an exercise where I get 3 integers and 2 operators one of ^,/,+,-,*,%.
And to evaluate the result the is a pre-defined precedence table for each of the six operators.
I have used Switch within a Switch 6 times for every operators 36 combinations in total as follow (example for ^)

```
 switch(oper1){
        case '^':
            switch(oper2){
                case '^':
                    result=first_Num^second_Num^third_Num;
                    printf("Result: %.2f",result);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    if(third_Num==0){
                        printf("Error");
                    }
                    else{
                        result=(first_Num^second_Num)/(float)third_Num;
                        printf("Result :%.2f",result);
                    }
                        break;
                case '-':
                    result=(first_Num^second_Num)-third_Num;
                    printf("Result: %.2f",result);
                    break;
                case '+':
                    result=(first_Num^second_Num)+third_Num;
                    printf("Result: %.2f",result);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result=(first_Num^second_Num)*third_Num;
                    printf("Result: %.2f",result);
                    break;
                case '%':
                    if(third_Num==0){
                        printf("Error");
                    }
                    else{
                        result=(first_Num^second_Num)%third_Num;
                        printf("Result: %.2f",result);
                    }
                    break;
                default:;
            }
    }
```

I was trying to use the ASCII value of each operator and by subtracting two operators to find out which operators are there and by positive and negative sign to determine the order.
For example if the first operator is / and second operator is * are given the it will be 47-42=5 and if the result is -5 it will be * first and / second.

I am trying to find the algorithm with the smallest numbers of checks available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be a matter of setting up an operator precedence table that maps each operator to it's precedence and a pointer to a function that performs the required operation.

Then your algorithm to calculate the results (hard coded for 2 operators and 3 integer arguments) would be something like the `calculate()` function below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* operator implementations */
int add(int a, int b) { return (a + b); }
int sub(int a, int b) { return (a - b); }
int mul(int a, int b) { return (a * b); }
int div(int a, int b) { return (a / b); }
int mod(int a, int b) { return (a % b); }
int xor(int a, int b) { return (a ^ b); }

struct operator
{
    char token;
    int precedence;
    int (*op)(int, int);
};

struct operator operators[] = {
/*  map operator token to precendence and implementation function */
    {'+', 1, add},
    {'-', 1, sub},
    {'%', 1, mod},
    {'*', 2, mul},
    {'/', 2, div},
    {'^', 4, xor},
};

struct operator *get_operator(char token)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<(sizeof(operators)/sizeof(struct operator)); i++)
        if (operators[i].token == token)
            return &operators[i];
    return (struct operator *)NULL;
}

struct operator *static_get_operator(char token)
{
    /* hard-coded but faster than iterating get_operator() above */
    switch (token) {
        case '+': return &operators[0];
        case '-': return &operators[1];
        case '%': return &operators[2];
        case '*': return &operators[3];
        case '/': return &operators[4];
        case '^': return &operators[5];
    }
   return (struct operator *)NULL;
}

int calculate(char op_token1, char op_token2, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    struct operator *op1 = get_operator(op_token1);
    struct operator *op2 = get_operator(op_token2);

    if (op1->precedence > op2->precedence)
        return op2->op(op1->op(arg1, arg2), arg3);
    else
        return op1->op(arg1, op2->op(arg2, arg3));
}

int main()
{
    int result;

    result = calculate('+', '*', 1, 2, 3);
    printf("result = %d\n", result);
    result = calculate('*', '+', 1, 2, 3);
    printf("result = %d\n", result);
    result = calculate('*', '^', 10, 10, 2);
    printf("result = %d\n", result);
    result = calculate('-', '-', 10, 10, 2);
    printf("result = %d\n", result);
    result = calculate('-', '/', 10, 10, 3);
    printf("result = %d\n", result);
}
```

This is of course limited to 2 operators and 3 arguments, and it needs error handling for invalid tokens and division by zero errors for `'/'` and `'%'` operations.